# why sonaqube doesn't find jsp vulnerabilities

Tags: jsp, sonarqube

I wrote a very simple JSP to test sonarqube. It contains the following lines:

```
<jsp:include page="header.jsp">
<input type="text" name="foo" value="<%= request.getParameter("foo") %>" />
```

As it is mentioned in the following links, sonarqube should recognize the two vulnerabilities--> using JSP expressions and dynamic includes. But I don't get any errors in this JSP file from sonarqube.

https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=Web%3AJspScriptletCheck

https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=Web%3ADynamicJspIncludeCheck

I use sonarqube-6.0 and sonar-scanner-2.7. Also, I have added the following line in my sonar-project.properties:
sonar.web.file.suffixes=.html,.xhtml,.rhtml,.shtml,.jsp

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful because the two rules you're talking about are part of the SonarQube Web plugin (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Web+Plugin) which is not part of the default SonarQube distribution. You need to explicitly install this plugin and activate those two rules to get the expected issues.

Comment: I did add web plugin and did all the steps to Analyze a Web Project and it seems that it is working fine. It finds errors such as "Favicons should be used in all pages", .. . But doesn't find the above mentioned errors: using JSP expressions and dynamic includes. I wonder if it needs any special settings?

Comment: Go to Administration > Global Configuration > Web and override the default value of "sonar.web.file.suffixes" property to make the pluging analyzing '.jsp' source files. Hopefully, this is the thing you forgot to configure.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I did add this "sonar.web.file.suffixes=.html,.xhtml,.rhtml,.shtml,.jsp" in my sonar-project.properties file. After adding this line to my property file it seems that it analyzes "jsp" files. isn't enough? do I need to do it as u explained (Go to Administration,...)?